# Why does (package) nslcd recommend nscd?

Tags: package-management, ldap

The two packages seem to do the same function (caching data)

I'm currently debugging LDAP client configuration, so I'm wondering if these packages are really useful.

Comment: @muru Why are you changing the title of my question ???  I was asking about *packages* ... I don't care about the manpages, I'm trying to understand the package dependencies...

Comment: When did I mention manpages?

Comment: "From man nscd" ...

Comment: Can't you read? Does `muru` read the same as `A.B.`?

Comment: anyway, can you explain why you changed the title, removing the important/meaning words ?

Comment: What important word did I omit? `package`? It's reasonably obvious when talking about software that recommendations are for packages.

Comment: And with the `package-management` tag, it's even more obvious.

Comment: I don't understand why *you* are determining the correct wording of *my* question.  A.B answers, which mention manpages,  show that it's worth to mention that I'm interested in  *package* management not services/daemon. Please revert the title.

Comment: Revert it yourself. Since A.B. answered even with the word in the title, I don't see how its presence made any difference. The question is yours, but members of the site can make edits. And for a person who can't read, you are getting pretty worked up about the language of the question.

Comment: Comments are not for discussion.  Take it up into chat or to meta if you want to continue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nscd` and `nslcd` are not the same and also not similar, read the man pages. `nscd` isn't neccessary but recommended by the package maintainers and for this reason `nslcd` recommends `nscd`.

---

From `man nscd`

```
DESCRIPTION
    Nscd caches libc-issued requests to the Name Service. If retrieving
    NSS data is fairly expensive, nscd is able to speed up consecutive
    access to the same data dramatically and increase overall system
    performance.  Nscd should be run at boot time by /etc/init.d/nscd.
```

From `man nslcd`

```
DESCRIPTION
    nslcd is a daemon that will do LDAP queries for local processes
    that want to do user, group and other naming lookups (NSS) or do user
    authentication, authorisation or password modification (PAM).
```

---

Perhaps you have read another description. My description says:

[nscd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/nscd)

> Name Service Cache Daemon

[nslcd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/nslcd)

> daemon for NSS and PAM lookups using LDAP

Comment: apt-cache show nslcd | grep Recommends         
 Recommends: nscd, libnss-ldapd | libnss-ldap, libpam-ldapd | libpam-ldap | libpam-krb5 | libpam-heimdal | libpam-sss, ldap-utils, bind9-host | host

Comment: Your comment should be added to the question to make it more clear what you are asking. But the manpage tell me both do 2 different things. nslcd=daemon. nscd=cacher.

Comment: I clearly understand now the difference  but please note that, before installing the concerned packages and accessing the correspondig manpages, if you read the package descriptions you have :    (nscd)    " A *daemon* which handles passwd, group and host lookups"  and (nslcd) " This package provides a *daemon* for retrieving user accounts and similar"...

Comment: Great. Time to accept the answer? Click on the check mark at the left side of the answer **;)**